# Java Script Methods are not working in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Very simple question. I just began learning JavaScript a few days ago, and I am using JSFiddle to run and test my code. I have this simple method I am trying to run in JSFiddle, but not sure why it is not running. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    fullName: function () {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
person.fullName();
```

Comment: You need to output something: `console.log(person.fullName());` Maybe you had first tried the code in the dev-console, where expression values are also automatically output?

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Comment: Your title should be updated. Your title is currently "Java Script". This should be changed to "JavaScript".

Answer (score 1):

The code you put up should run just fine, but take a look at what your function `fullName` is actually doing in the comments below:

```
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  fullName: function() {
    // notice you are returning a string value
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
};

// store the value you are returning in a variable
var personFullName = person.fullName();

// print out full name to the console
console.log(personFullName);
```

Check out this resource for the `return` keyword and happy coding!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return